# How to do a Sampling on the boundary of Brillouin zone in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, brillouin-zone

I use VASP to do my DFT calculation. I have to do a self consistent calculation to generate my CHGCAR. I want to ask is there anyway to write the KPOINTS file to generate K-meshing grid which can exactly lying in  $(\frac{\pi}{a} , \frac{\pi}{a}, \frac{\pi}{a})$ point in square Brillouin zone boundary? As I used Monkhost-Pack grid, which can only guarantee that your point grid can be located at Gamma point.

Comment: In principle it is possible to add the k-points that you want explicitly in VASP, is this what you are asking, or are you asking more generally about sampling k-point grids (irrespective of VASP)?

Comment: @ProfM Yes. But when I use this method It will give an error as follow:  
"error in ibzkpt_hf: two k-point are equivalent". But I have check that no K-point are equivalent in my file except the TRIM in boundary which connected by reciprocal lattice vector and differ by a sign.

Comment: I would say that two points separated by a reciprocal lattice vector *are* equivalent; why do you want to include both?

Comment: @ProfM Because I turned off the symmetry TAG  in the INCAR file, and the KPOINT grid should be symmetry in the Brillouin zone.  I try to fit run VASP2Wannier90 that's why I want to include the high symmetry point in my file.

Comment: I don't have experience with VASP2Wannier90, but it sounds surprising that it should not be able to handle the fact that adding a reciprocal lattice vector leads to an equivalent wave vector... I would recommend updating the question with all these extra details and perhaps also updating the tags to see if someone with experience with VASP2Wannier90 can help...

Comment: If you turn off the symmetry with `ISYM = -1`, the point group symmetry found for your structure is not imposed on the Kohn–Sham orbitals. However, there is no way to turn off periodic boundary conditions in VASP! So $\vec{k}$ points separated by  reciprocal lattice vectors are always equivalent.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.